# Functional refactor of Ant Design async tree returns key error

Tags: antd

I am trying to refactor the class-based Ant Design tree into a functional component. When I expand a top-level parent, the console warns me of the following error:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `ParentsTree`.
in ContextTreeNode (at ParentsTree.js:39)
in ParentsTree (at Parents.js:11)
...
```

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Tree } from 'antd';
const { TreeNode } = Tree;

export default function ParentsTree() {
    const [treeData, setTreeData] = useState([
        { title: 'Expand to load', key: '0' },
        { title: 'Expand to load', key: '1' },
        { title: 'Tree Node', key: '2', isLeaf: true },
    ]);

    function onLoadData(treeNode) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            if (treeNode.props.children) {
                resolve();
                return;
            }
            setTimeout(() => {
                treeNode.props.dataRef.children = [
                    { title: 'Child Node', key: `${treeNode.props.eventKey}-0` },
                    { title: 'Child Node', key: `${treeNode.props.eventKey}-1` },
                ];
                console.log(treeNode.props.dataRef);
                setTreeData(prevTreeData => [...prevTreeData, treeNode]);
                resolve();
            }, 1000);
        });
    };

    function renderTreeNodes(data) {
        return data.map(item => {
            if (item.children) {
                return (
                    <TreeNode title={item.title} key={item.key} dataRef={item}>
                        {renderTreeNodes(item.children)}
                    </TreeNode>
                );
            }
            return <TreeNode key={item.key} {...item} dataRef={item} />;
        });
    };

    return (
        <Tree loadData={onLoadData}>
            {renderTreeNodes(treeData)}
        </Tree>
    );
}
```

My guess is that the culprit is `setTreeData(prevTreeData => [...prevTreeData, treeNode]);`, but I cannot figure out how to set the state correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!

For any others trying the same thing, this is the correct way to update the state to force a refresh: `setTreeData([...treeData]);`. The rest of the code is correct.